# Certain images loading from /wp-admin/ which our server is blocking, resulting in a 403

Tags: images

Some images are being blocked by our WAF (see hidden information) because the website is attemping to load them through /wp-admin/ - "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=kernel&p=image&src="

We are not using image optimizer plugins and we have disabled WordFence. It has happened on previous versions of YooTheme/WordPress and is happening with and without "serve .webp" images enabled, although it seems to specifically be happening to .jpg files.